# Mysql в wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести базу данных на свой сайт. Создав при этом таблицу на страничке и заполнив данные таблицы, данными с бд.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите вывести информацию из типовых таблиц Wordpress, то можно воспользоваться встроенными классами, такими как WP_Query, WP_Term_Query, WP_Comment_Query. Например так:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'posts_per_page' => 10
]);
```

Далее необходимо пройти стандартным циклом Wordpress.

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $table = '<table>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $date  = get_the_time('d.m.Y');

        $table .= <<<ROW
<tr>
    <td>{$title}</td>
    <td>{$date}</td>
</tr>
ROW;
    }

    // Обязательно сбросить после цикла, 
    // чтобы не повлиять на глобальную переменную $wp_query!
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $table .= '</table>';

    echo $table;
}
```

Либо прибегнуть к помощи класса wpdb, обязательно чз глобальную переменную $wpdb, например так:

```
global $wpdb;

// Если параметры запроса приходят от пользователя, нужно сделать так
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT post_title, post_date 
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}
    WHERE post_type = %1$s AND posts_status = %2$s
    ", [ $_REQUEST['post_type'], $_REQUEST['post_status'] ]
);

// Получаем результаты в виде ассоциативного массива (или еще как-то)
$items = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

Дальше можно воспользоваться циклом foreach:

```
if ( $items ) {
    $table = '<table>';
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        $title = $item['post_title'];
        $date  = date_create( $item['post_date'] )->format('d.m.Y');

        $table .= <<<ROW
<tr>
    <td>{$title}</td>
    <td>{$date}</td>
</tr>
ROW;           
    }
    $table .= '</table>';

    echo $table;
}
```

Методы класса wpdb позволяют выполнить любой запрос к базе данных.

Подробнее смотрите в документации: [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)